# Changing the Text of a Span Class by script (magento)

Tags: html, magento

Hello. First of all, sorry for eventual English mistakes, since I'm Brazilian:

I have a ecommerce based on magento 1.9.2.2, and the company that hosts it does not allow the user to access the server files (header, body, footer, etc). You can only  edit the website via css and html external scripts.

So there's this div:

```
                <p class="old-price">
            <span class="price-label">De:</span>
            <span class="price" id="old-price-1046">
                R$2.500,00                </span>
        </p>

                        <p class="special-price">
                **<span class="price-label">Preço Promocional</span>**
            <span class="price" id="product-price-1046">
                R$2.299,90                </span>
            </p>
```

Which I just need to replace the text "Preço Promocional" (within the "price-label" class) for "Por:"

So far I've tried:
document.getElementsByClassName('price-label').innerHTML = 'Por:';
javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('price-label').innerHTML = 'Por:';
javascript:void(document.getElementsByClassName('price-label').innerHTML = 'Por:');

Thanks for any help in advance...

Comment: Welcome Rodrigo. Can you not change the HTML file directly? `**<span class="price-label">Por:</span>**` It is quite dangerous to change it using a class, because you may be overriding any other `class="price-label"` in the entire document

Comment: Hi! Well, can not, unfortunately. And yes, I've noticed that when I tweaked some CSS lines. But hopefully, there's no other similar class in the website.
But in the CSS lines I could specify which one I wanted to change by it's path, e.g:
.product-info .price-box span.price{
 font-size:15px;
versus
.price-info .price-box span.price{
 font-size:18px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**getElementsByClassName** returns a collection and not a single element. In your example you have two elements with the same class name, you'd access the first one with the index **0** and the second one with the index **1**.

```
<p class="old-price">
    <span class="price-label">De:</span>
    <span class="price" id="old-price-1046">R$2.500,00</span>
</p>

<p class="special-price">
    <span class="price-label">Preço Promocional</span>
    <span class="price" id="product-price-1046">R$2.299,90</span>
</p>

<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName('price-label')[1].innerHTML = "Por:";
</script>
```

This code will change the second one that says "Preço Promocional" for "Por:"

**//EDIT**

Now that I've seen the full page, in javascript you could achieve this with:

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('.special-price .price-label').forEach(function(node) {
    node.innerHTML = 'Por: ';
});
</script>
```

This will target all elements with the class **price-label** inside elements with the class **special-price**, loop through each and change their contents. This will change the main, related and recommended products as long as it's put after they are created.

As a **preferred** alternative, try using the following css:

```
<style>
.special-price .price-label {
    display:none !important;
}
.special-price::before {
    content: 'Por: ';
}
</style>
```

This should hide the content and then prepend the text on the parent and doesn't required to be placed at the end to work.

**// EDIT** (To address new information added in the comments for this answer)

In order to avoid changing the homepage, you can use the **:not()** css' pseudo-class (info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)) to exclude those instances of **special-price** that are found within the homepage. I searched for and id or class that was unique to the homepage (found the class **cms-home** on the body tag for the homepage) so I'm using that to both exclude and target the different **price-label**s. I also changed the font-size to match the original one:

```
<style>
// this targets price-label that's NOT in the homepage
body:not(.cms-home) .special-price .price-label {
    display:none !important;
}
body:not(.cms-home) .special-price::before {
    content: 'Por: ';
    font-size:15px;
}
// this targets price-label on the homepage
.cms-home .special-price .price-label {
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

If I understood correctly, on the homepage you're simply hiding the text, while on the other pages you're replacing it with "Por: ", this should do it (hopefully) unless there's another special case I'm unaware of.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much Juan.
My mistake was, after all, not trying "[1]" in one of my tests. I'm such a noob :).

Comment: No problem! If you're using javascript you can always do console.log() to see what you're actually getting (HTMLCollection[2]) or check on w3schools.com [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) to see definition and usage. Good luck!

Comment: Hi again Juan. I thought that it worked for the whole page, but I recently noticed that it worked for half of it. Because, after the product descriptions, there's the recommended products (from magento). And in each products boxes (or grid), that same code I've mentioned in the main post repeats... But the script are not affecting those, even though they are piratically the same. Here's two examples: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G9YSJ8SBBKY1

Comment: And here's one full page... Which you can see the script working for the main product, but not for the recommended ones: https://www.rbaimportados.com/doogee-s95-pro.html

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I've just read your comment and updated the answer to reflect the changes that should fix it. I recommend trying the change in css(style tags) rather than the javascript so see if that works for you first. If not, delete and use the javascript.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, the reason why it only worked for "half of it(page)" is because the original javascript only targeted a single element on the page (the second that matched the criteria) but on your whole page you have a number of elements that's variable.

Comment: Hi again Juan! I've tried both codes and, unfortunately, the CSS doesn't works perfectly well with the hole site, because:
1) If I use your code without any changes, it adds the "Por:" sentence in the homepage as well.
2) If I tweak it the path for ".price-info .special-price::before", then, fix the homepage, but the "Recommended products" boxes goes back to "Preço promocional".
3) So, the only code that's working 100% right now is the Javascript one (although I agree with you, CSS would be bettter...

Do you think that it is any form to use the CSS?

Thanks again mate!

Comment: P.S: And Javascript is also nice because it doesn't change the fonts sizes. But that's just a small plus.

Comment: Hey Rodrigo! Whoops! Didn't know about that case, I added an EDIT at the end of my answer with a new css that should address both dealing with the homepage and the text size! Hopefully it works!

Comment: It worked perfectly. Can't thank you enough. You not only helped me (several times), but I also learned a lot. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<script>
            $('.special-price .price-label').text('Por:');
</script>
```

Comment: are you check the console?

Comment: I was about to answer you, but Juan (below) already gave the solution. Thanks again mate!